# Create a automation grammar that generates a language whose sequences do not repeat digits

Tags: automation, grammar

You need to create a automation grammar that generates chains of numbers in which no digit is repeated. The chains can be of any length, i.e. from 1 to 10,because all the numbers can be used
A single digit is also considered a sequence
I have a grammar for three digits, but for all 10 I can't make a grammar in any way:

```
S->1A|2B|3C
A->2D|3E|εD|εE
B->1D|3G|εD|εG
C->1E|2G|εE|εG
D->3|ε
E->2|ε
G->1|ε
```

Example:
allowed:
1234567890
1235678
09841
154
etc

not allowed:
1231
09877
11544
etc

Comment: What's the problem other than the fact that you'll need really a lot of productions?

Comment: @rici When writing grammar, I ran out of the entire alphabet after the first three transitions

Comment: @rici OK, I have a grammar. how can it be simplified or implemented without iterating through the switch states?

Comment: it's not possible to simplify much. So you'll need more than a simple alphabet to represent non-terminals. Subscripts are handy.